# Capture still image from video stream on a Linux Access Control Server

Tags: linux, image, video-streaming, video-capture

I am currently adding features to a custom access control server at work and what I would like to do is access the camera at the door and store at least 1 still image after the door is unlocked (each door has an RFID reader that interfaces with this server).

For example one of the Cameras is a Vivotek FD8136, which has multiple output steams that i can access as long as I have a username and password......
With this camera I can access a stream by going to the local address http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8002/video2.mjpg

I am just unsure how to go about saving just a simple image to the server from that stream.....

any and all help will be appreciated. I know I am probably trying to over complicate it in my head....

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible way to do it using avconv... But if anyone knows a better way please feel free to leave a message so that if anyone else needs this it can help them as well.

With avconv it is the command as follows (i believe it will work with ffmpeg as well)

avconv -i http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8002/video2.mjpg -vframes 1 output%.jpg

That will output a single file for testing but a bash script with date can make the file name with a date and time in it easily. Then when needed just run the desired script and there is an image to access later.